# Using VRS for concurrent request

Tags: optaplanner

**We need to use a single instace of VRS to support concurrent request.**

We have a requirement where multiple different users should be able to create a route plan for different vehicles and locations same time. However, looking at VRS functionality, I am not able to understand how applications supports it. For demo, when I create a different route using different browser, it always merges first and second request and give one single result.

Just a little more elobration on the question:

We are aiming to convert requests as REST API endpoints which will be invoked by different uses same time for their usecase.

Eg. Request 1: Vehicle 1&2 with 50 locations. VRS can calculate route & give one message with all detailed calculations for request1.

Request 2: Vehicle 3 & 4 with 40 locations. So VRS can calculate route which later we can get as one message with all detailed calculations limited to request 2.

Both requests can be submitted same time & application should considered as separate requests without getting merged.

Is there a way to add request ID or any other paramaters to achive this?

Comment: Are you looking at `optaweb-vehicle-routing`?

Comment: Yes. Can you pls. suggest if need to use anything else here?

Comment: The `SolverManager` API supports multi-tenancy (see optaplanner-docs), and your request ID is known as a `problemId`, but optaweb-vehicle-routing doesn't support multi-tenancy yet in it's REST API's. Also, it looks like you don't need real-time planning, but only nightly batch planning. But you do need maps integration. So all the pieces are there (in optaplanner-quickstarts, optaplanner-examples and optaweb-vehicle-routing) but not yet set together.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I use  optaplanner-quickstarts, optaplanner-examples and optaweb-vehicle-routing, would it also help to solve requestId issue?  problemId part of it? Any pointer here would great help. For REST part, application UI is invoking route plan (very similar to demo) hence considering REST approch. Since many users can use same feature simultaneously to create their own route, having support for multiple threads with thread safe is needed

Answer (score 0):

For multi-tenant solving, [the SolverManager API](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.3.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#solverManager) is ideal:

```
public class TimeTableService {

    // tenantId is Long, but it can also be String or UUID
    private SolverManager<TimeTable, Long> solverManager;

    // Returns immediately, call it for every dataset
    public void solveBatch(Long tenantId) {
        solverManager.solve(tenantId,
                // Called once, when solving starts
                this::findById,
                // Called once, when solving ends
                this::save);
    }

    public TimeTable findById(Long tenantId) {...}
    public void save(TimeTable timeTable) {...}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Seems I missed mentioning that I am new for OptaPlanner & trying it first time. Sorry if this sounds too naive, do I need to add any of the modules along with VRS or best to use basic enginee along with other modules

Comment: Wondering if anyone has done a similar implementation, would be happy to understand also open for consulting engagements to get it implemented